# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component 2021

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

````
  const getData = async () => {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user-info");
    if(jsonValue != null) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(jsonValue))
    } else {
     setUser(null) 
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2aSC.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3zMY.png
````

Edit, Code Login:
Below is the complete code of the file where the error is found.

the Error Return is:
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

And also:
Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

This error is located at:
in Perfil (at SceneView.tsx:122)

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import {
      View,
      Image,
      Text,
      TouchableOpacity,
      StyleSheet,
      SafeAreaView,
      Platform,
    } from "react-native";
    import { icons, images } from "../constants";
    import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
    import { theme } from "../styles/theme";
    import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async- 
    storage";

    export const Perfil = () => {
      const [user, setUser] = useState<any>();

      const [loaded] = useFonts({
        Inter: require("../../assets/fonts/Inter-Bold.ttf"),
        InterRegular: require("../../assets/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf"),
      });

      if (!loaded) {
        return null;
      }

     useEffect(() => {
      let mounted = true;
      const getData = async () => {
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user-info");
        if (mounted === true) {
          if(jsonValue != null) {
            setUser(JSON.parse(jsonValue))
           } else {
            setUser(null) 
         }
       }
     };
    
    getData();
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    } 
    }, []);


    function renderHeaderSection() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        {/* Image */}
        <Image source={images.UserProfileImg} style={styles.userImg} />

        {/* User Name */}
        <Text style={styles.userName}>{user?.user?.givenName} {user?.user?.familyName}</Text>

        {/* Email */}
        <Text style={styles.userEmail}>{user?.user?.email}</Text>

        {/* Button Edit Profile */}
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonProfile}>
          <Text style={styles.textButtonProfile}>Editar Perfil</Text>
          <Image
            source={icons.ArrowRightImg}
            style={{ tintColor: theme.colors.white, width: 8, height: 14 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
    }

    function renderPreferencesSection() {
    return (
      <View>
        {/* Preferences */}
        <View style={styles.preferences}>
          <Text style={styles.textPrefences}>Preferences</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
    }

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        {renderHeaderSection()}
        {renderPreferencesSection()}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.white,
      paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 50 : 0,
      alignItems: 'center'
     },
     header: {
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
     },
     userImg: {
      width: 70,
      height: 70,
      borderRadius: 100,
     },
    userName: {
      fontSize: 18,
      color: theme.colors.black,
      paddingVertical: 6,
      fontFamily: "Inter",
    },
    userEmail: {
      fontSize: 14,
      color: theme.colors.black,
      fontFamily: "InterRegular",
    },
    buttonProfile: {
      marginTop: 20,
      height: 40,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary,
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      borderRadius: 20,
      paddingHorizontal: 20,
      flexDirection: "row",
    },
    textButtonProfile: {
      color: theme.colors.white,
      fontFamily: "InterRegular",
      fontSize: 14,
      paddingRight: 14,
    },
    preferences: {
      minWidth: '90%',
      height: 40,
      backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
      borderRadius: theme.border.radius,
      marginTop: 30,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      paddingLeft: 20
    },
    textPrefences: {
      fontSize: 14,
      color: theme.colors.gray4
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` can potentially try to update the state of your component when it is unmounted. Which is why you're getting the warning.

For example, `getData` is called by the `useEffect`, and and while it's waiting, the component could become unmounted.  So if your asyncronous `AsyncStorage.getItem` call resolves after the component gets unmounted, it will try to call `setUser` on a component that is no longer mounted.

What you can do is only call `setUser` if it is mounted:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    const getData = async () => {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user-info");
      if (mounted === true) {
        if(jsonValue != null) {
          setUser(JSON.parse(jsonValue))
        } else {
         setUser(null) 
        }
      }
    };
    
    getData();
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    } 
  }, []);
```

In this pattern, a local variable `mounted` guards `setUser` from being called if its `false`.  Which we can ensure will be set false when the component unmounts by including a [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) as the return of the `useEffect`.

Comment: Unfortunately the error message doesn't help since we don't have context on what `Perfil (at SceneView.tsx)` is.  Try at the very least refreshing your page.  You're getting a `Rendered more hooks than previous render` error.

Comment: Hello, I changed the post and added the file that is using the function, could you analyze it, please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is probably with `useFonts`;

If you take a look at [the code](https://github.com/byCedric/use-expo/blob/main/packages/font/src/use-fonts.ts), you can see that it calls a state modifier following an async call:

```
useEffect(() => {
        loadAsync(map).then(() => setLoaded(true))
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line
```

This is enough to cause the error in question.

The best you can do is to either ignore the warning, write your own version of the hook, or use a module like [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package), to monkey patch its behaviour.